# Add directory to path globally on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, path

How can I add my own directory to PATH without editing my local profile's .bash_profile or .bashrc?

I need to make the scripts in the directory universally accessible from any user that is logged in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could add the following in `/etc/bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/your/directory"
```

Comment: thanks, in ubuntu 12.10 `/etc/bashrc` is `/etc/bash.bashrc` :)

Comment: This is incorrect also because it only affects bash users.

Comment: /etc/bash.bashrc is the location. But refer to */etc/environment* as this is the more recent way to achieve what was asked.

Answer (score 75):

You should modify the file /etc/environment.

Comment: Modify it how? I tried using the same as what I would have put in profile or bashrc and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried adding the path to environment file. It didn't work. However, the Raghuram's suggestion worked like a charm.

Comment: This would be the best solution on systemd machines. It requires a reboot or logout/in to affect processes system wide. The same as bashrc

Answer (score 11):

Better */etc/profile*, so it should work for other shells, as **sh**

Comment: Is `/etc/profile` better than `/etc/bashrc`, or `/etc/environment`, or both?